# Htaccess issue - url with multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I use this htaccess for multiple parameters like bank, state,district & branch.
But it only format bank not others...???
I need it for:
www.domain.com/bank/ .....(It works)
www.domain.com/bank/state/
www.domain.com/bank/state/district/
www.domain.com/bank/state/district/branch/

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=   ([^&]+)&state=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&]+)&state=([^&]+)&district=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&]+)&state=([^&]+)&district=([^&]+)&branch=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4/%5/? [L,R=301]


# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Kindly provide solution for this...Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex and reverse order of redirect rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&\s]+)&state=([^&\s]+)&district=([^&\s]+)&branch=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4/%5/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&\s]+)&state=([^&\s]+)&district=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=   ([^&\s]+)&state=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?bank=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%2/? [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Hi, one more question regarding same above issue... After rewrite url i can't able to access value using $_REQUEST, so i use

Comment: If it is `POST` data then it gets lost after an external redirect. See updated answer.